# Giving a new user the ability to run ONLY the passwd program

Tags: ubuntu, root, sudo

I am using Ubuntu.

Let's say I've created a new user called abc.

As root using sudo visudo, how do I give abc the ability to run ONLY the passwd program? Please advise

Comment: `passwd` doesn't need root to run, and if you give someone `sudo passwd` they can change any password on the system, including root's, which gives them access to do anything they want anyway.

Comment: yes I have notice that, but I want to give abc the ability to only run passwd and nothing else. How do i achieve that?

Comment: i think i solved it myself. I used sudo chown -R abc:abc /etc/passwd